# in AS3, removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME) is not working

Tags: actionscript-3, event-handling, event-listener, game-loop, enterframeevent

I have been dealing with this problem for days already. I am at my wits' end!
I can't seem to find a definitive answer anywhere on any of the forums, documentation, etc.

Everything looks fine at first run, or when I load a next level for the user to play. But if the user hits the ESC key to load a different level, the ENTER FRAME listener does not get removed and it duplicates all the triggers in it, showing the player going really fast, and all funky, because it builds on top of the previously instantiated ENTER FRAME listener.

I don't know if I have a problem of an anonymous function, or an unknown instance being referenced in my removeEvent... command... Bottom line, I give up and I need this working HELP!!!

Here's the code:

```
function initPlay():void
{ 
    //code here determining what display object to add to the list and assign it to the currentLevel variable (a movieclip)

    if(userIsLoadingOtherLevel){
        removeEnterFrameListener();
        addChild(currentLevel);
        }
    if(userIsGointToNextLevel)
        addChild(currentLevel);

    currentLevel.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame);
    function onEnterFrame(event:Event):void
    {
        //collision detection, parallax scrolling, etc, etc is done here.
        if(allCoinsCollected)
            loadNextLevel();
        if(ESCKeyPressed)
            ESCKeyPressHandler();
    }
    function loadNextLevel():void
    {
        removeChild(currentLevel);
        newLevelToLoad++
        removeEnterFrameListener();
        initPlay();
    }

    function ESCKeyPressHandler():void
    {
        removeChild(currentLevel);
        initPlay();
    }
    function removeEnterFrameListener();
    {
        currentLevel.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,onEnterFrame)
        trace("currentLevel.hasEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME) = "+currentLevel.hasEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME)); //outputs TRUE if called from loadNextLevel but FALSE if called from initPlay() !!!
    }
}
```

I also tried to add and remove the eventListener to stage, MovieClip(Root), or nothing at all and the result is always the same.

I know that there may be other ways to design such a process, but please note I am not really flexible at the moment on doing this because the project is very long (about 4000 lines of code) and removing the ENTER FRAME this way, crazy or not should still work!!

THANK YOU in advance for anyone willing to help.

Comment: Does it work if you use loadNextLevel instead of ESCKeyPressHandler?

Comment: I have the feeling also that what's happening is that the ENTER_FRAME Event Listener gets attached to all of the childs of the currentLevel display Object, and when I remove it to add a different level, it still remains in some of the currentLevel Children, or something like that. I think this may be happening because after loading a new level, the player still collides with "invisible" objects probably still present from the prior ...

Comment: Yes Pan, that works just fine. I only have a problem when when I use the ESCKeyPress handler. It just doesn't remove it!

Comment: Is the above code correct? I ask because you seem to be defining functions inside of the `initPlay()` function. Syntax wise, that's perfectly OK. But logically, it maybe part of your problem. Perhaps it's just a typo, and you forget to paste/type in a closing bracket...

Comment: The `trace()` statement is a great debugging tool. Put `trace()` statements at the beginning of each method. Then run your code in both scenarios (when it works properly and when it fails). Compare the output you get from the trace statements and perhaps you will see where things are going haywire. Your current work around may end up biting you later by causing performance issues w/having a bunch of enter frame listeners being executed.

Comment: I was able to get around it by using a higer scope variable called "loadingNewGame" and change it to true from initPlay triggering from onEnterframe the removeEnterFrameListener(). This did the trick. I will post the code later. It's still unknown why it works. Can someone explain why it works? documentation on the Event.ENTER_FRAME won't help. I will post code with solution once the site time allows it.

Comment: @SunilD. I did define those functions inside the initPlay() function on purpose to narrow the scope. Is this a bad idea? Suggestions? Why? Thanks much for the help!

Comment: Actually, yes, I think that is your problem... I was just about to say that it was probably ok and that my simple mind was having a problem understanding it. But as I thought it through, all of your observations make sense now... I will post an answer and try to explain.

Comment: Thanks @SunilD. Yes, I still don't know why it would work on one, and not on another. I think it would be very useful to figure it out. This ENTER_FRAME event could get sticky sometimes!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem appears to be the nested functions inside the `initPlay()` method.

Each time you call `initPlay()` you are defining **new** functions. Some of these nested functions call `initPlay()` themselves.

Functions are objects (memory references). So each time you call `initPlay()` you are making new references to new functions. So when you try to remove an event listener, you're only able to remove one of these event handlers (the one in the current scope of execution).

I'm not sure if I'm explaining this clearly, perhaps this example will help. I'll use numbers to represent the references to each function, and a simple scenario that is similar to yours:

```
function example():void
{
    addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, mouseClickHandler);

    function mouseClickHandler(event:Event):void
    {
        if (someCondition)
        {
            example();
        }
        else
        {
            removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, mouseClickHandler);
        }
    }
}
```

When we run this function the first time, a new function is defined within the scope of the `example()` function. Lets use the number 1 to represent the reference to this nested function. `someCondition` is `true` on the first time around, and so the `example()` function is called again.

On the second execution of the `example()` function, a new reference to the mouse event handler is created (#2). We also add the event listener again. At this point, there are two event handling functions in memory, and both will be executed when the event is dispatched.

Let's say that in the second invocation of `example()` that `someCondition` is `false` and now we want to remove the listener.  When we call:

```
removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, mouseClickHandler);
```

It's referring to event handler #2. Event handler #1 still exists, and because it's hidden in the scope of the first invocation of `example()` it can't be removed here.

My simple example breaks down after this... but I hope it makes it clear why your event handlers shouldn't be nested inside a function.  Admittedly, this is difficult to describe and even more so in a real world example like yours.  But I'm pretty confident that this is the source of most, if not all, of the issues you describe.

Comment: Not sure if I explained this clearly... and perhaps the example was overkill. Comment here if I can explain something more clearly...

Comment: By the way, using nested functions for event handlers (or even anonymous functions) is OK, but not when the logic gets complicated like in your situation. That's where it will be better to to move those functions to the "outer" scope so that there's no confusion about what's being added/removed.

Comment: Actually you made perfect sense. What I am going to do then is move the nested functions outside unless it's absolutely necessary to leave them nested. This should also simplify other tasks during development. My temporary fix of adding the out scope variable fixed it since it allows me to remove the event handler form the "enter frame" itself, but it does seem to be way too complicated for what it does... THANK YOU VERY MUCH @SunilD !! It will take me a while to move all those functions outside, and a lot of null references may pop up because of it, but I think it's worth it for simplicity

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I was able to get around this without changing the scope of the nested functions (although I agree that would be the preferred solution) by creating a boolean variable called "loadingNewGame" and changing it to true from outside the onEnterFrame (in fact, this assignment was done from initPlay() and then from onEnterframe I called removeEnterFrameListener() function. This did the trick.

here's the code in case anybody is interested:

```
// package, and other code here.

var loadingNewGame:Boolean = new Boolean(false);
function initPlay():void
{ 

    //code here determining what display object to add to the list and assign 
    //it to the currentLevel variable (a movieclip)

    if(userIsLoadingOtherLevel)
        {
        loadingNewGame = true;
        removeEnterFrameListener();
        addChild(currentLevel);
        }
    if(userIsGointToNextLevel)
        addChild(currentLevel);

    loadingNewGame:Boolean = false;
    currentLevel.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame);
    function onEnterFrame(event:Event):void
    {
        if(loadingNewGame)
            removeChild(currentLevel);
        //collision detection, parallax scrolling, etc, etc is done here.
        if(allCoinsCollected)
            loadNextLevel();
        if(ESCKeyPressed)
            ESCKeyPressHandler();
    }
    function loadNextLevel():void
    {
        removeChild(currentLevel);
        newLevelToLoad++
        removeEnterFrameListener();
        initPlay();
    }

    function ESCKeyPressHandler():void
    {
        initPlay();
    }
    function removeEnterFrameListener();
    {
        currentLevel.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,onEnterFrame)
        trace("currentLevel.hasEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME) = "+currentLevel.hasEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME)); 
        //outputs true
    }
```